# How to Reference First Non-null String in a Column - Cloudera Impala / Apache Hive / Spark SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala

I am using Impala SQL. I currently have a database with 3 columns: `Account`, `Date`, `Type`.

Under `Type` there are various data strings describing the associated type, but some are equal to `'UNKNOWN'` and some are `null`.

I'd like to create another column `Fixed_Type`. The values in `Fixed_Type` should come from the `Type` column.

- If the value in `Type` is either `null` or `'UNKNOWN'`, it should get last valid value in the `Type` column, partitioned by account and ordered by date.
- If the partition begins with `null` or `'UNKNOWN'`, then the value in `Fixed_Type` should be the first valid value from `Type`.

For example:

```
Account | Date | Type   |  Fixed_Type
1         Jan     data1     data1
1         Feb   'UNKNOWN'   data1
1         Mar     null      data1
2         Apr     data2     data2
2         May     null      data2
2         Jun     null      data2
2         Jul     data3     data3
3         Feb   'UNKNOWN'   data4
3         Mar   'UNKNOWN'   data4
3         Apr     data4     data4
```

I started doing this in Oracle but then realized there is no functionality analogous to `IGNORE NULLS` implemented in Impala.

This is what I was thinking to do in Oracle (I realize this only handles forward fill on nulls):

```
select account, date, type, 
       case when type is null 
            then last_value(type ignore nulls)
                 over (partition by account order by date) 
            else type 
       end as fixed_type
```

Comment: do you have `row_number()` ? Looks easy replace that with a self join.

Comment: Yes I do have that.

Comment: I guess your date is a date or number otherwise you can't order by text

Comment: Correct. it's in the Impala date format and I can cast it as needed for ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name ( Acct, Dt, Type ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2016-01-01', 'Data1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2016-02-01', 'UNKNOWN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2016-03-01', NULL      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2016-04-01', 'Data2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2016-05-01', NULL      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2016-06-01', NULL      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2016-07-01', 'Data3'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2016-02-01', 'UNKNOWN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2016-03-01', 'UNKNOWN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2016-04-01', 'Data4'   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Acct,
       Dt,
       Type,
       Fixed_Type
FROM   (
  SELECT r.Acct,
         r.Dt,
         r.Type,
         t.type AS fixed_type,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY r.Acct, r.dt
                             ORDER BY SIGN( ABS( t.dt - r.dt ) ),
                                      SIGN( t.dt - r.dt ),
                                      ABS( t.dt - r.dt ) ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name r
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         table_name t
         ON (    r.acct = t.acct
             AND t.type IS NOT NULL
             AND t.type <> 'UNKNOWN' )
)
WHERE   rn = 1
ORDER BY acct, dt;
```

**Explanation**:

If you join the table to itself so both tables have the same account number then you can compare each row per account with all the other rows in that same account. However, we aren't interested in comparing to all the rows but just to the rows that aren't `NULL` or `'UNKNOWN'` so we get the join condition:

```
ON (    r.acct = t.acct
    AND t.type IS NOT NULL
    AND t.type <> 'UNKNOWN' )
```

A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is used just in case there is an account number that has all `NULL` or `'UNKNOWN'` values for its type so that rows aren't excluded.

Then it is a matter of finding the row that is most recent. In Oracle, if you subtract one date from another then you get the number of days (or fraction of days) difference - so:

- `SIGN( ABS( t.dt - r.dt ) )` will give `0` if the two dates are identical or `1` if they are different. Ordering by this first means that if there is a value with the same date then it will be preferred over non-identical dates;
- `SIGN( t.dt - r.dt )` will return `0` if the two dates are identical (but that's already been filtered on in the previous statement) or `-1` if the compared date is before the current row or `+1` if it is after - this is used to prefer a before date to an after date.
- `ABS( t.dt - r.dt )` will order the dates by closest together.

So the `ORDER BY` clause effectively states: `ORDER BY` identical dates first, then dates before (closest to `r.dt` first) and finally dates after (closest to `r.dt` first).

Then that is all placed in an in-line view and filtered to get the best match for each row (`WHERE rn = 1`).

**Output**:

```
      ACCT DT                  TYPE    FIXED_TYPE
---------- ------------------- ------- ----------
         1 2016-01-01 00:00:00 Data1   Data1      
         1 2016-02-01 00:00:00 UNKNOWN Data1      
         1 2016-03-01 00:00:00         Data1      
         2 2016-04-01 00:00:00 Data2   Data2      
         2 2016-05-01 00:00:00         Data2      
         2 2016-06-01 00:00:00         Data2      
         2 2016-07-01 00:00:00 Data3   Data3      
         3 2016-02-01 00:00:00 UNKNOWN Data4      
         3 2016-03-01 00:00:00 UNKNOWN Data4      
         3 2016-04-01 00:00:00 Data4   Data4
```

Comment: @Addie Explanation added.

Answer (score 2):

I use postgresql to test the query, so not 100% sure if you can make it work in your system. `WITH` can be replace with subquerys. Also have to change your Date to number so `ORDER BY` work as intended.

- **enumerateWords**: Create an enumerated list for valid words.
- **createFlag**: Set a flag so you can validate when the next group will start.
- **createGrp** : Using the flags and `SUM()` you create the groups.
- Finally you join the group with the enumerated list to assign the `Fixed_Type`

  - special condition in the JOIN `c.grp = 0 and e.rn =1` for when the first row is `NULL` or `'UNKNOWN'`

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/38dc2/11)**

```
WITH enumerateWords as (
    SELECT "Account", "Date", "Type",
           row_number() over (partition by "Account"
                              order by "Date") rn
    FROM Days  
    WHERE "Type" <> '''UNKNOWN''' AND "Type" IS NOT NULL   
),  createFlag as (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN "Type" = '''UNKNOWN''' OR "Type" IS NULL 
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
             END as FLAG       
  FROM Days  
), createGrp as ( 
  SELECT *,
         SUM(FLAG) OVER (PARTITION BY "Account" 
                         ORDER BY "Date") as grp         
  FROM createFlag  
)
SELECT c.*, e."Account", e."Date", e."Type" as "Fixed_Type"
FROM createGrp c
JOIN enumerateWords e
  ON c."Account" = e."Account"
 AND (     c.grp = e.rn   
       OR (c.grp = 0 and e.rn = 1)
     )
```

**OUTPUT**

As you can see createGrp display `Fixed_Type` type from the value on DB, but enumerateWords create it from `Type`.

And you can see how flag and grp work together to see detect the changes.

```
|                      createGrp                       ||      enumerateWords       |
|---------|------|-----------|------------|------|-----||---------|----|------------|
| Account | Date |      Type | Fixed_Type | flag | grp || Account | rn | Fixed_Type |
|---------|------|-----------|------------|------|-----||---------|----|------------|
|       1 |    1 |     data1 |      data1 |    1 |   1 ||       1 |  1 |      data1 |
|       1 |    2 | 'UNKNOWN' |      data1 |    0 |   1 ||       1 |  1 |      data1 |
|       1 |    3 |    (null) |      data1 |    0 |   1 ||       1 |  1 |      data1 |
|---------|------|-----------|------------|------|-----||---------|----|------------|
|       2 |    4 |     data2 |      data2 |    1 |   1 ||       2 |  1 |      data2 |
|       2 |    5 |    (null) |      data2 |    0 |   1 ||       2 |  1 |      data2 |
|       2 |    6 |    (null) |      data2 |    0 |   1 ||       2 |  1 |      data2 |
|       2 |    7 |     data3 |      data3 |    1 |   2 ||       2 |  2 |      data3 |
|       2 |    8 |    (null) |      data3 |    0 |   2 ||       2 |  2 |      data3 |
|---------|------|-----------|------------|------|-----||---------|----|------------|
|       3 |    9 | 'UNKNOWN' |      data4 |    0 |   0 ||       3 |  1 |      data4 | <= 
|       3 |   10 | 'UNKNOWN' |      data4 |    0 |   0 ||       3 |  1 |      data4 | <= 
|       3 |   11 |     data4 |      data4 |    1 |   1 ||       3 |  1 |      data4 |
                                                                    ^^^ special case 0 = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Juan. At a glance this looks great. I'll adapt this to my environment and will promptly accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Good Luck, I try to make it the more generic posible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, similar to Juan Carlos's, using the analytic function `count` and a `case` expression to create the groups in one pass.

I created more input data to test, for example, what happens when an account only has `null` and/or `'UNKNOWN'` as type (making sure the left outer join works as intended).

```
create table table_name ( acct, dt, type ) as
select 1, date '2016-01-01', 'Data1'   from dual union all
select 1, date '2016-02-01', 'UNKNOWN' from dual union all
select 1, date '2016-03-01', null      from dual union all
select 2, date '2016-04-01', 'Data2'   from dual union all
select 2, date '2016-05-01', null      from dual union all
select 2, date '2016-06-01', null      from dual union all
select 2, date '2016-07-01', 'Data3'   from dual union all
select 3, date '2016-02-01', 'UNKNOWN' from dual union all
select 3, date '2016-03-01', 'UNKNOWN' from dual union all
select 3, date '2016-04-01', 'Data4'   from dual union all
select 3, date '2016-05-01', 'UNKNOWN' from dual union all
select 3, date '2016-06-01', 'Data5'   from dual union all
select 4, date '2016-02-01', null      from dual union all
select 4, date '2016-03-01', 'UNKNOWN' from dual;

SQL> select * from table_name;

      ACCT DT         TYPE
---------- ---------- -------
         1 2016-01-01 Data1
         1 2016-02-01 UNKNOWN
         1 2016-03-01
         2 2016-04-01 Data2
         2 2016-05-01
         2 2016-06-01
         2 2016-07-01 Data3
         3 2016-02-01 UNKNOWN
         3 2016-03-01 UNKNOWN
         3 2016-04-01 Data4
         3 2016-05-01 UNKNOWN
         3 2016-06-01 Data5
         4 2016-02-01
         4 2016-03-01 UNKNOWN

14 rows selected.
```

**Query**:

```
with
     prep(acct, dt, type, gp) as (
       select acct, dt, type, 
              count(case when type != 'UNKNOWN' then 1 end)
                             over (partition by acct order by dt)
       from   table_name
     ),
     no_nulls(acct, type, gp) as (
       select acct, type, gp
       from   prep
       where  type != 'UNKNOWN'
     )
select p.acct, p.dt, p.type, n.type as fixed_type
from   prep p left outer join no_nulls n
on     p.acct = n.acct and (p.gp = n.gp or p.gp = 0 and n.gp = 1)
order by acct, dt;
```

**Output**:

```
      ACCT DT         TYPE    FIXED_TYPE
---------- ---------- ------- ----------
         1 2016-01-01 Data1   Data1
         1 2016-02-01 UNKNOWN Data1
         1 2016-03-01         Data1
         2 2016-04-01 Data2   Data2
         2 2016-05-01         Data2
         2 2016-06-01         Data2
         2 2016-07-01 Data3   Data3
         3 2016-02-01 UNKNOWN Data4
         3 2016-03-01 UNKNOWN Data4
         3 2016-04-01 Data4   Data4
         3 2016-05-01 UNKNOWN Data4
         3 2016-06-01 Data5   Data5
         4 2016-02-01
         4 2016-03-01 UNKNOWN

14 rows selected.
```